# Double integral property with absolute value

Tags: calculus, integration

I am in a university, and I stumbled into a property of the double integral:

$$\left|\iint_D f(x,y)~dx~dy\right|\leq \iint_D |f(x,y)|~dx~dy$$

I do not get it. What does this mean? And why is this?

Thank you for help.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. See [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers.

Comment: $|4 + \phantom{1}^- 1| \leq |4| + |-1|$.  This is the integration version of the same fact.

Comment: It is just the triangle equality but generalized to integration rather than sums.  The fact that it is a double integral is irrelevant.  It could just as easily have been a single integral, a triple integral, riemann integration, lebesgue integration, etc...  You should know that $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$

Comment: thanks. Sometimes you have to think simple, it seems.